# How to copy a whole directory structure with a certain file size limit?

Tags: bash, command-line

For some reasons, I need to do a data clone.

In which I need to copy the whole structure of a huge directory, 
but I'd like to only copy those files which are smaller than 1MB(with their hierarchy unchanged), because there are many giant temp files I want to avoid clone with.

Which utilities or commands I should use to achieve that goal?

Does zip command can realize this goal directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a --max-size option to rsync which will exclude files from over a certain size from being copied from one directory to another. From the man page;

```
--max-size=SIZE
    This tells rsync to avoid transferring any file that is larger than the specified SIZE. The SIZE value can be suffixed with a string to indicate a size multiplier, and may be a fractional value (e.g. lq--max-size=1.5mrq). 
This option is a transfer rule, not an exclude, so it doesn't affect the
    data that goes into the file-lists, and thus it doesn't affect deletions. It just limits the files that the receiver requests to be transferred. 
The suffixes are as follows: lqKrq (or lqKiBrq) is a kibibyte (1024),
    lqMrq (or lqMiBrq) is a mebibyte (1024*1024), and lqGrq (or lqGiBrq) is a gibibyte (1024*1024*1024). If you want the multiplier to be 1000 instead of 1024, use lqKBrq, lqMBrq, or lqGBrq. (Note: lower-case is also accepted for all values.) Finally, if the suffix ends in either lq+1rq or lq-1rq, the value will be offset by one byte in the indicated direction. 
Examples: --max-size=1.5mb-1 is 1499999 bytes, and --max-size=2g+1 is
    2147483649 bytes.
```